# Allow range of numbers in input type- plunker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, validation

Please refer to the plunker. http://plnkr.co/edit/EzMmIUYSa11Pl6vbwV7o?p=preview

As you can see, there are two input field present and a description in front of each of them.

Currently it allows users to allow positive and negative values in both of them. I want it to allow only positive values from the range 0 to 10 in the first field and negative values with the range -1 to 0.

how can i achieve this thing here ? can someone please help.

HTML code

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  Positive from 0 to 10 only<input type="text" ng-model="amount" format="number" /><br><br>

  Negative from -1 to 0 only<input type="text" ng-model="amount1" format="number" />
</div>
```

JS code

```
var app = angular.module('App',[]);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) { 
});

app.directive('format', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
return {
    require: 'ngModel',

    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
        if (!ctrl) return;


        ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function (a) {
            return $filter(attrs.format)(ctrl.$modelValue);
        });


        ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
            var plainNumber = viewValue.replace(/[^\d|\-+]/g, '');
            elem.val($filter('number')(plainNumber/100,2));
            return plainNumber;
        });
    }
};
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a directive posted on github by Cohen Adair. This worked pretty well for me and i had to only work on the css part and a bit here and there so as to get it working into my project. Here is the link

http://cohenadair.github.io/angular.number-input/

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTML5 input type

```
<input type="number" max="10" min="0" step="0.01" ng-model="amount" format="number" />
<input type="number" step="0.01" max="1" min="0" ng-model="amount1" format="number" />
```

Comment: @dipesh- i tried that but it still allows me to type a number greater than the values mentioned in min and max. I want something like obstructing a user to type a number greater than 10 if max is set to 10.

Comment: @dipesh- morever the input type is text is in my case. hence min and max wont work.

Comment: @Ayesha If you need number then why are you using text fields?

Comment: @dipesh- there are some directives i have used so that the input fields allow commas on the fly and a decimal point... with numbers, it difficult to get such type of validation...